# Django Unittest URL call with a different Django User

Tags: python, django, api

I have the following `unittest` class in Django.

```
class TmpUrlTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        test_group = Group('test_group')
        test_group.save()
        self.api_url = "/tmp_url/"

        self.test_user = User.objects.create(username='user1')
        self.test_user.set_password('pass')
        self.test_user.save()
        self.test_user.groups.add(test_group)

    def test_url(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.api_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Now in my get call, I want the user to be `user1`. Any ways to do this while making a call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login as the user before sending the request

```
self.client.login(username='user1', password='pass')
```